# calling another python script in the main file does not execute

Tags: python

I have two main python scripts in my project:

`sftpConnector.py` and `fileIterator.py`

`sftpConnector.py` establishes connection to an SFTP server and downloads some file, it however does not call any other script. It has only function: `establisher()`

While, `fileiterator.py` also has one function `iterator()` it calls two other scripts: `folderGenerator.py` and `dataProcessor.py()`

When independently called, both the scripts, `sftpConnector.py` and `fileIterator.py` execute properly without any issues, however, when I try to create a main.py file to call these two scripts one after the other, it does not work.

The `main.py` looks like this:

```py
import sftpConnector
import fileIterator


if __name__ == 'main':
    folder_name = input('File name:\n')
    print('folder_name')

    sftpConnector.establisher(folder_name)

    fileIterator.iterator(folder_name)
```

This `main.py` file runs the first script and function, `sftpConnector.establisher(folder_name)` however it does not even go inside the second script. I am not sure what's going on here.

Also, not sure if this will help, but neither of the script are returning anything.

Comment: Does `sftpConnector.establisher()` ever actually return?  Until that happens, the next line of the main script isn't going to execute.

Comment: There is no return statements in either one of the script, the sftpConnector downloads some files from the server and stores it in local directory. the second file, fileiterator.py is supposed to use these downloaded files to call other functions and do the processing.

Comment: standard procedure: insert `print` statements to see where a script hangs. Consider providing a [mre].

Comment: check / correct code indentation.

Comment: Or better yet set break points in your ide and debug (better than adding print statements).

Comment: I would argue that your script isn't running, at all. `"__main__"` not `"main"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your run guard should be

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

That’s how to ensure that your code only runs if run as a module (versus being imported). You accidentally checked for the wrong name (“main”) and I’m guessing that’s why the code in your `if` block isn’t running. It’s an easy mistake to make as it’s easy to assume that `__name__` refers to the name of your file when you run your script directly, but it doesn’t; it refers to the environment where the toplevel code is run. The line `if __name__ == '__main__':` is asking the question: “Is this script the toplevel one?”

Comment: @OneMadGypsy thanks for fixing my quote characters. I’m on my phone and was having trouble with that.

Comment: I hope you don't mind. I added a little info to the end of your answer. Your answer is already correct. IMO, it's better to butter it up a little than create an identical answer that just includes 3 extra sentences of info.

Comment: I think that’s fine. I may edit it a bit to fit the style of the rest of my answer.